# How to make children in a LinearLayout occupy the same ammount of space

Tags: xml, android-layout, android

I have a LinearLayout with four children. Each children is a linear layout with an ImageView and a TextView (centered below ImageView). It happens that a TextView is a bit bigger than the others so it takes more space, than the others which causes trouble cause I need them all to have exact the same size (because I have another LinearLayout below the one I'm talking right now and I all the children be aligned). This strikes me weird because I've already set

`android:layout_weight="1"`

which I thought makes the children in a LinearLayout occupy the same space.
Here is my code, for better understanding:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/line_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/line_2"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/sights_selector" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/corfu_textView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Sights"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">


                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/activities_selector" />

                           <TextView
                               android:id="@+id/epirus_textView"
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:text="Activities"
                               android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/accomodation_selector" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vlora_textView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Accomodation"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                   <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/villages_selector" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vlora_textView"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Villages"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use weight sum in parent layout and weight in childs :)

Comment: I've already set weight in children, if weight sum isn't declared it is calculated automatically from parents children.That means it's 4 and each child has 1 weight. So that means they must occupy the same space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that, in addition to the other answers, the TextViews have width="wrap_content". Try this instead:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/line_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/line_2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/sights_selector" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/corfu_textView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Sights"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">


                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/activities_selector" />

                       <TextView
                           android:id="@+id/epirus_textView"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:text="Activities"
                           android:textSize="10sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/accomodation_selector" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/vlora_textView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Accomodation"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

               <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/villages_selector" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/vlora_textView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Villages"
                            android:textSize="10sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `layout_weight`. Make sure that you set `layout_width ="0dp"` for a parent with horizontal orientation and `layout_height="0"` for vertical orientation.

Find more info from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Answer (score 1):

See the below code

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/line_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/line_2"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/sights_selector" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/corfu_textView"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Sights"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">


                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/activities_selector" />

                           <TextView
                               android:id="@+id/epirus_textView"
                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:gravity="center"
                               android:text="Activities"
                               android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/accomodation_selector" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vlora_textView"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Accomodation"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                   <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/villages_selector" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/vlora_textView"
                               android:layout_width="match_parent"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="Villages"
                                android:textSize="10sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `layout_width` of the `LinearLayout` to something like `0dp` for the `layout_weight` attribute to apply.